# How to achieve brightness + contrast in WebGL?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am trying to apply window level similar to [this example](https://rawgit.com/chafey/cornerstone/master/example/windowlevel/index.html) ,drag your mouse over the image to see the brightness + contrast effect.

But I want to achieve the same using WebGL ,as GPU will process them more faster than CPU.

Here's what I have done:

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 attrVertexPos;
attribute vec2 attrTextureCoord;

varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(attrVertexPos, 0.81);
    vTextureCoord = attrTextureCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
#endif

varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uImage;
uniform float brightnessFactor;
uniform float contrastFactor;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uImage, vTextureCoord) *(brightnessFactor/contrastFactor);
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected according the link given above.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
var isMouseDown = false;

document.getElementById('canvas').onmousedown = function() { isMouseDown = true  };
document.getElementById('canvas').onmouseup   = function() { isMouseDown = false };
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        var intWidth = $('canvas').innerWidth();
        var intHeight = $('canvas').innerHeight();
        var x = (e.clientX/intWidth)*100;
        var y = (e.clientY/intHeight)*100;

        console.log(x/10 + ' :: ' + y/10);

        brightnessVal = x/10;
        gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "contrastFactor"), brightnessVal);
        contrastVal = y/10;
        gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "brightnessFactor"), contrastVal);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in pixel manipulation. You're just multiplying by a coefficient (also, the names of the coefficient you use are incorrect), where as in the linked exampled something a bit more complicated is happening. Some colour range (described by its center and width) from the source image gets expanded to full [0,1] range:

```
newColor = (oldColor - rangeCenter) / rangeWidth + 0.5
```

Why is it doing this is beyond my knowledge (the page is an example for medical imaging library and I don't know anything about it). Nevertheless, I've managed to port the formula to your code. First, fragment shader changes:

```
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
    precision highp float;
#else
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uImage;

// New uniforms
uniform float rangeCenter;
uniform float rangeWidth;

void main(void) {
    vec3 c = texture2D(uImage, vTextureCoord).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
        // The above formula, clamped to [0, 1]
        clamp((c - windowCenter) / windowWidth + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0),
        // Also, let's not screw alpha
        1
    );
}
```

As for JavaScript, I've taken the liberty to make it a bit closer to linked example:

```
var isMouseDown = false,
    // Initially we set "equality" colour mapping
    rangeCenter = 0.5,
    ragneWidth = 1,
    lastX, lastY;

document.getElementById('canvas').onmousedown = function(e) {
    lastX = e.clientX;
    lastY = e.clientY;
    isMouseDown = true
};
document.getElementById('canvas').onmouseup = function() {
    isMouseDown = false
};
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        var intWidth = $('canvas').innerWidth();
        var intHeight = $('canvas').innerHeight();

        // Change params according to cursor coords delta
        rangeWidth += (e.clientX - lastX) / intWidth;
        rangeCenter += (e.clientY - lastY) / intHeight;

        gl.uniform1f(
            gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rangeWidth"),
            rangeWidth
        );

        gl.uniform1f(
            gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rangeCenter"),
            rangeCenter
        );

        lastX = e.clientX;
        lastY = e.clientY;
    }
};
```

Old answer:

> The problem is that, according to your code, you don't redraw the
>   picture after `mousemove` event. Just insert a draw call (or several
>   draw calls) with appropriate parameters after setting uniforms. For
>   example, it may look like this:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(e) {
>     if (isMouseDown) {
>         // your code
>
>         gl.drawArrays(/* params, e.g gl.TRIANGLES, 0 and vertex count */); 
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> A better way would be using `requestAnimationFrame` callback to
>   redraw. To do that, define a `draw` function, which will make the draw
>   call for you and use it a `requestAnimationFrame` callback:
>
> ```
> function draw () {
>     /* your draw calls here */
> }
>
> document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(e) {
>     if (isMouseDown) {
>         // your code
>
>         requestAnimationFrame(draw);
>     }
> };
> ```

P.S. Also, I'm intersted, where does this `#ifdef GL_ES` thing come from? It's **incorrect** to set `highp` precision based on `GL_ES` macro. Hardware doesn't have to support it according to the standard. The right way would be:

```
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
    precision highp float;
#else
    precision mediump float;
#endif
```

Comment: Actually ,I have the requestAnimationFrame already implemented and it gives me wrong results : var render = function () {
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

Comment: OK, can you go a little bit in details: what is wrong with the image you're seeing? Can you link a page or jsfiddle so I could take closer look?

Comment: sure , let me create a fiddle for you

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/1/ , however somehow it was not taking the brain image from https://rawgit.com/chafey/cornerstone/master/example/windowlevel/index.html after saving it as image as well, but you could try with both the images and compare the results

Comment: @SubhasishDash Amended the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kirill ,you save a lot of time for me.

Comment: Also, If you are interested, would you like to teach me OpenGL, I will pay you hourly. Pls let me know your hourly charges in case you are interested

Comment: @SubhasishDash Sorry, I have full-time job now. But I can recommend a good book for learning GL and basics of CG: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Interactive-Computer-Graphics-Top-Down-Shader-Based/dp/027375226X/ref=mt_paperback?_encoding=UTF8&me=).

Comment: okay thanks for your recommendation., I will definitely look on to that book . I have another  opened webgl question from a long time, can you please check it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434440/how-to-scroll-two-different-texturesin-a-scrolling-manner-fiddle-attached-for)?